# CUDA Measuring the time between 2 _syncthread() point

Tags: c++, cuda, profiling, gpu

I searched a bit but all things I found could only be annotated in CPU code, how could I measure partial time inside kernel between 2 _syncthread() of 1 threadblock? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use the `clock()` or `clock64` function as described [in the programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#time-function).

Search the cuda tag on `clock64` for additional examples of its usage.